# Perl Selenium::Remote::Driver and threads

Tags: multithreading, selenium, perl

I have a program i'm writing in perl using Selenium::Remote::Driver that is also using threads.

Is S:R:D not thread friendly? When I start a thread and try to open a selenium driver instance, I would get a random error(dont have on hand, I got past this). For now, I set a shared variable that makes it so only one selenium instance is executing commands at a time, but i'm still running into errors, right now is with setting cookies in the selenium instance.

Is there a way around this?

This is how my program goes for instance:

they both setup driver as

```
$driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new( 'auto_close' => 0,
                          'browser_name' => 'chrome',
                           extra_capabilities' => { 
                            'chromeOptions' => {
                       'args' => ['window-size=1920,1080',
                            'blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false']}});
```

[Thread 1] Starts
[Thread 2] Starts
[Thread 2] Randomly won the race of getting selenium started first, does stuff
[Thread 1] Waits til thread 2 is done doing selenium commands.
....Fast forward both threads are done setting up....
[Thread 1] Wins the race now and starts setting a cookie in theirenter code here selenium instance on a webpage we're on, www.mywebsite.com

`$driver->add_cookie("anything", "1", "/", 'www.mywebsite.com','1','1');`

this thread ends up terminating because of the error

`Thread 1 terminated abnormally: Error while executing command: invalid argument: invalid argument: invalid 'secure' (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129) at /Library/Perl/5.18/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 402 thread 1. at /Library/Perl/5.18/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 353 thread 1.`

No matter what we change it to, this will still error out, anyone have any ideas? is this really just not thread friendly and i have to try something else?

Comment: It is possible that the C component of that module or a related module isn't thread-safe. You can sometimes get around that by only loading the module from within the threads.

Comment: yea, i tried that as well actually but also still getting same result.